# keep ng-init variable in synch with assigned $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two nested `ng-repeat` in both I intesively use respective `$index`. So for readability sake I "renamed" the first $index using `ng-init` (i.e.: `ng-init="backupIndex = $index"`). At the starting point everithing is fine, and `backupIndex` is always equal to `$index`.

The problem is if I remove element from the collection binded to the `ng-repeat` then `backupIndex` goes out of synch with `$index`.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vGvmhnvcfEyDicqsPXxC?p=preview). How can I maintain `$index` and `backupIndex` in synch?

Comment: you need provide more code in post, not only in plunker

Comment: why you need in _backupIndex_, instead you can use _$index_ directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it if u can omit the `ng-init` part and,

```
<ul ng-repeat="value in values">
  <span style="display: none"> {{ backupIndex = $index }}</span>
  <li>backUp: <b>{{backupIndex}}</b> $index: <b>{{$index}}</b> <button ng-click="rem(backupIndex)">Remove</button></li>
</ul>
```

`<span style="display: none"> {{ backupIndex = $index }}</span>` this line will assign `backupIndex` value of `$index` and it will sync with the `$index`

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUq5KGgcDwTBOFRkWuhA?p=preview)

---

`<ul ng-repeat="value in values" ng-init="backupIndex = $index">`

`ng-init` will execute only first time and it will create a `ng-repeat`'s child scope variable called `backupIndex` and assign it the value of `$index` and `backupIndex` not sync with the `$index`.

```
var ngInitDirective = ngDirective({
    priority: 450,
    compile: function() {
        return {
            pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

this is the `angular.js` directive for `ng-init`. what it do is get the expression in `ng-init` and Executes the expression on the current scope and returns the result.

In this case: `ng-init` expression is `backupIndex = $index` then in `scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit);` *(`attrs.ngInit` is having the expression of `backupIndex = $index`)* line `backupIndex = $index` expression executes on the `ng-repeat`'s scope. that mean at this point there is a variable called `backupIndex` in `ng-repeat`'s scope, with the value of `$index` and that's it.

Comment: @LVarayut _ngInit_ run only link function

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to rename the first index to backupIndex since every ng-repeat creates a new scope, and to if you are inside the second ng-repeat and you want to reach the firsts index, all you need to do is access that using

```
$parent.$index
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/w8btAZfbGgNGLoYFCTP2?p=preview